# Change MovieClip associated with class in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How do I change the MovieClip(graphic) that is associated to a class with actionscript 3? For example I have a MovieClip in my library that is named playButton and it's class has the same name. How do I change the MovieClip associated with the class to be playButton2?

The way I display my MovieClips right now is:

```
private var playButton_:playButton = new playButton();
//in constructor
playButton_.x = 300;
playButton_.y = 300;
addChild(playButton_);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just change it in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the variable as being a `MovieClip` type, after that you can assign it an object of either `playButton` or `playButton2` type. Note though, just changing the variable's value is not enough to remove the old object it referred from display list. You will need to handle these situations manually.

```
private var _playButton:MovieClip;
// in constructor
_playButton=new playButton();
_playButton.x = 300;
_playButton.y = 300;
addChild(_playButton);
```

Then, once you don't need the old button, you have to drop the button off display list correctly, remove all the listeners attached, then you simply create a new object and go forward.

```
// elsewhere
_playButton=new playButton2();
_playButton.x = 300;
_playButton.y = 300;
addChild(_playButton);
```